# Workflow: A post in one channel automatically creates a post in another

Tags: channel-entries, workflow

I have a customer requirement where they're asking that EE automatically generate a blog post when a post in another channel is created (e.g., we post a product and there's a blog post about it).

Aside from doing it in some funky way where I combine the channel but separate out the posts via category, I can't think of a really streamlined way to do it.

I'm guessing it could be done using ACT or something, but I'm not sure the best way to approach this. Any tips to get me headed in the right direction would be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Sure - use an extension which fires on the [entry_submission_end hook](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/api/channel_entries/#entry-submission-end).

Check that `$meta['channel_id']` matches your Product channel, then take the data from `$meta` and `$data` to create a new entry (just an array of data) for your Blog channel.

Lastly, pass that array to the [Channel Entries API](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_entries.html#save-entry) and you should be good.